# Membership tables and other tables in one DB or separate?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-membership

I have an ASP.NET site with membership tables in a Main_DB for the site.  Can I add more tables for the site for other data needed for the site or should that data be in another database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have one database, I'd put the ASP.NET membership tables into that database.

If you want to share the users and roles amongst several apps, it's probably easier to put the ASP.NET membership and role stuff into a separate database.